# Wagtail wagtailcore issue "NOT NULL constraint failed: wagtailcore_page.translation_key"

Tags: django, migration, save, wagtail

I am getting the error message on any call of Page model save method.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: wagtailcore_page.translation_key
```

One of the Page Models looks like this

```
@register_query_field('home_page')
class HomePage(BasePageAbstract):
    
body = StreamField(
        BasePageAbstract.stream_blocks + [
        ],
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    content_panels = BasePageAbstract.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body', classname="full")
        ]
    parent_page_types = None

    graphql_fields = [
        GraphQLString("body")
    ]
```

with abstract class

```
class BasePageAbstract(Page):

title_image = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image',
    null=True,
    blank=False,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='+'
    )

sub_title_text = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

stream_blocks = [
    ('collection', CollectionBlock()),
    ("rich_text", blocks.RichtextBlock()),
]

content_panels = [MultiFieldPanel([
    ImageChooserPanel('title_image'),
    FieldPanel('sub_title_text', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':5})),
])] + Page.content_panels


class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

Django = "==2.2.5"

wagtail = "==2.6.1"

In my database the table wagtailcore_page and the field translation_key are created. So I think it could be a problem with the uuid creation.

I tried deleting and re-migrating the Page models - no success.
I also tried updating wagtail - no success.

I do not really have a clue on how to get closer to a solution of this problem.

I'd appreciate any help. I will supply more info if helpful.

Best regards!

Comment: Yes, you need to supply your Page model definition along with the save() call.

Comment: I added one page model and the abstract page class. The save method is not overwritten. It is called from the wagtail admin.